# How to convert Unicode to Preeti (ASCII) using javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

I am new to javascript and recently joined Bachelor.In my first semester,I was given project to convert Unicode to Preeti (Nepali font) which is ASCII code.The Dictionary for conversion was listed as :

unicodeToPreetiDict = \

```
{
    "अ": "c",
    "आ": "cf",
    "ा": "f",
    "इ": "O",
    "ई": "O{",
    "र्": "{",
    "उ": "p",
    "ए": "P",
    "े": "]",
    "ै": "}",
    "ो": "f]",
    "ौ": "f}",
    "ओ": "cf]",
    "औ": "cf}",
    "ं": "+",
    "ँ": "F",
    "ि": "l",
    "ी": "L",
    "ु": "'",
    "ू": '"',
    "क": "s",
    "ख": "v",
    "ग": "u",
    "घ": "3",
    "ङ": "ª",
    "च": "r",
    "छ": "5",
    "ज": "h",
    "झ": "´",
    "ञ": "`",
    "ट": "6",
    "ठ": "7",
    "ड": "8",
    "ढ": "9",
    "ण": "0f",
    "त": "t",
    "थ": "y",
    "द": "b",
    "ध": "w",
    "न": "g",
    "प": "k",
    "फ": "km",
    "ब": "a",
    "भ": "e",
    "म": "d",
    "य": "o",
    "र": "/",
    "रू": "?",
    "ृ": "[",
    "ल": "n",
    "व": "j",
    "स": ";",
    "श": "z",
    "ष": "if",
    "ज्ञ": "1",
    "ह": "x",
    "१": "!",
    "२": "@",
    "३": "#",
    "४": "$",
    "५": "%",
    "६": "^",
    "७": "&",
    "८": "*",
    "९": "(",
    "०": ")",
    "।": ".",
    "्": "\\",
    "ऊ": "pm",
    "-": " ",
    "(": "-",
    ")": "_"
}
```

Left part of character is Unicode whereas right part is Preeti font maybe.

You can check the conversion after writing code in this sample site:
http://unicode.shresthasushil.com.np/

If we give input as कलम (unicode),it must be converted to Preeti.I need source code in javascript or php to convert unicode to preeti.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you already solved this, are you looking for alternate methods?

Comment: I am looking for source code to convert unicode to ASCII in javascript

Answer (score 1):

One way is to hard code it with a switch

```
function convert(x)
{
  switch(x)
    {
        case "अ":
            return "c";
        case "आ":
            return "cf";
        case "ा":
            return "f";
        case "इ":
            return "O";
        case "ई":
            return "O{";
        case "र्":
            return "{";
        case "उ":
            return "p";
        case "ए":
            return "P";
        case "े":
            return "]";
        case "ै":
            return "}";
        case "ो":
            return "f]";
        case "ौ":
            return "f}";
        case "ओ":
            return "cf]";
        case "औ":
            return "cf}";
        case "ं":
            return "+";
        case "ँ":
            return "F";
        case "ि":
            return "l";
        case "ी":
            return "L";
        case "ु":
            return "'";
        case "ू":
            return '"';
        case "क":
            return "s";
        case "ख":
            return "v";
        case "ग":
            return "u";
        case "घ":
            return "3";
        case "ङ":
            return "ª";
        case "च":
            return "r";
        case "छ":
            return "5";
        case "ज":
            return "h";
        case "झ":
            return "´";
        case "ञ":
            return "`";
        case "ट":
            return "6";
        case "ठ":
            return "7";
        case "ड":
            return "8";
        case "ढ":
            return "9";
        case "ण":
            return "0f";
        case "त":
            return "t";
        case "थ":
            return "y";
        case "द":
            return "b";
        case "ध":
            return "w";
        case "न":
            return "g";
        case "प":
            return "k";
        case "फ":
            return "km";
        case "ब":
            return "a";
        case "भ":
            return "e";
        case "म":
            return "d";
        case "य":
            return "o";
        case "र":
            return "/";
        case "रू":
            return "?";
        case "ृ":
            return "[";
        case "ल":
            return "n";
        case "व":
            return "j";
        case "स":
            return ";";
        case "श":
            return "z";
        case "ष":
            return "if";
        case "ज्ञ":
            return "1";
        case "ह":
            return "x";
        case "१":
            return "!";
        case "२":
            return "@";
        case "३":
            return "#";
        case "४":
            return "$";
        case "५":
            return "%";
        case "६":
            return "^";
        case "७":
            return "&";
        case "८":
            return "*";
        case "९":
            return "(";
        case "०":
            return ")";
        case "।":
            return ".";
        case "्":
            return "\\";
        case "ऊ":
            return "pm";
        case "-":
            return " ";
        case "(":
            return "-";
        case ")":
            return "_";
    }  
}
console.log(convert("ऊ"));
```

And when you're sure it's working as intended and done testing, you can smash it into one line so you dont waste text editor space.

```
function convert(x){
  switch(x) {case "अ": return "c"; case "आ": return "cf"; case "ा": return "f"; case "इ": return "O"; case "ई": return "O{"; case "र्": return "{"; case "उ": return "p"; case "ए": return "P"; case "े": return "]"; case "ै": return "}"; case "ो": return "f]"; case "ौ": return "f}"; case "ओ": return "cf]"; case "औ": return "cf}"; case "ं": return "+"; case "ँ": return "F"; case "ि": return "l"; case "ी": return "L"; case "ु": return "'"; case "ू": return '"'; case "क": return "s"; case "ख": return "v"; case "ग": return "u"; case "घ": return "3"; case "ङ": return "ª"; case "च": return "r"; case "छ": return "5"; case "ज": return "h"; case "झ": return "´"; case "ञ": return "`"; case "ट": return "6"; case "ठ": return "7"; case "ड": return "8"; case "ढ": return "9"; case "ण": return "0f"; case "त": return "t"; case "थ": return "y"; case "द": return "b"; case "ध": return "w"; case "न": return "g"; case "प": return "k"; case "फ": return "km"; case "ब": return "a"; case "भ": return "e"; case "म": return "d"; case "य": return "o"; case "र": return "/"; case "रू": return "?"; case "ृ": return "["; case "ल": return "n"; case "व": return "j"; case "स": return ";"; case "श": return "z"; case "ष": return "if"; case "ज्ञ": return "1"; case "ह": return "x"; case "१": return "!"; case "२": return "@"; case "३": return "#"; case "४": return "$"; case "५": return "%"; case "६": return "^"; case "७": return "&"; case "८": return "*"; case "९": return "("; case "०": return ")"; case "।": return "."; case "्": return "\\"; case "ऊ": return "pm"; case "-": return " "; case "(": return "-"; case ")": return "_"; } 
}
```

And so if you had a string of unicode characters, your code might look like this:

```
function convert(x){
  switch(x) {case "अ": return "c"; case "आ": return "cf"; case "ा": return "f"; case "इ": return "O"; case "ई": return "O{"; case "र्": return "{"; case "उ": return "p"; case "ए": return "P"; case "े": return "]"; case "ै": return "}"; case "ो": return "f]"; case "ौ": return "f}"; case "ओ": return "cf]"; case "औ": return "cf}"; case "ं": return "+"; case "ँ": return "F"; case "ि": return "l"; case "ी": return "L"; case "ु": return "'"; case "ू": return '"'; case "क": return "s"; case "ख": return "v"; case "ग": return "u"; case "घ": return "3"; case "ङ": return "ª"; case "च": return "r"; case "छ": return "5"; case "ज": return "h"; case "झ": return "´"; case "ञ": return "`"; case "ट": return "6"; case "ठ": return "7"; case "ड": return "8"; case "ढ": return "9"; case "ण": return "0f"; case "त": return "t"; case "थ": return "y"; case "द": return "b"; case "ध": return "w"; case "न": return "g"; case "प": return "k"; case "फ": return "km"; case "ब": return "a"; case "भ": return "e"; case "म": return "d"; case "य": return "o"; case "र": return "/"; case "रू": return "?"; case "ृ": return "["; case "ल": return "n"; case "व": return "j"; case "स": return ";"; case "श": return "z"; case "ष": return "if"; case "ज्ञ": return "1"; case "ह": return "x"; case "१": return "!"; case "२": return "@"; case "३": return "#"; case "४": return "$"; case "५": return "%"; case "६": return "^"; case "७": return "&"; case "८": return "*"; case "९": return "("; case "०": return ")"; case "।": return "."; case "्": return "\\"; case "ऊ": return "pm"; case "-": return " "; case "(": return "-"; case ")": return "_"; } 
}


var str = "आअाअअ";


for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    console.log(convert(str[i]));
}
```

Make sure that in your html file you have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

---

If for some reason you can't get this method to work, there are some other methods I found out there regarding splitting using charCodeAt.

An example of this kind of method would be like so :

```
var str = "आअाअअ";


var arr = stringToArray(str);
console.log(arr);



function convert(x){
  switch(x) {case "अ": return "c"; case "आ": return "cf"; case "ा": return "f"; case "इ": return "O"; case "ई": return "O{"; case "र्": return "{"; case "उ": return "p"; case "ए": return "P"; case "े": return "]"; case "ै": return "}"; case "ो": return "f]"; case "ौ": return "f}"; case "ओ": return "cf]"; case "औ": return "cf}"; case "ं": return "+"; case "ँ": return "F"; case "ि": return "l"; case "ी": return "L"; case "ु": return "'"; case "ू": return '"'; case "क": return "s"; case "ख": return "v"; case "ग": return "u"; case "घ": return "3"; case "ङ": return "ª"; case "च": return "r"; case "छ": return "5"; case "ज": return "h"; case "झ": return "´"; case "ञ": return "`"; case "ट": return "6"; case "ठ": return "7"; case "ड": return "8"; case "ढ": return "9"; case "ण": return "0f"; case "त": return "t"; case "थ": return "y"; case "द": return "b"; case "ध": return "w"; case "न": return "g"; case "प": return "k"; case "फ": return "km"; case "ब": return "a"; case "भ": return "e"; case "म": return "d"; case "य": return "o"; case "र": return "/"; case "रू": return "?"; case "ृ": return "["; case "ल": return "n"; case "व": return "j"; case "स": return ";"; case "श": return "z"; case "ष": return "if"; case "ज्ञ": return "1"; case "ह": return "x"; case "१": return "!"; case "२": return "@"; case "३": return "#"; case "४": return "$"; case "५": return "%"; case "६": return "^"; case "७": return "&"; case "८": return "*"; case "९": return "("; case "०": return ")"; case "।": return "."; case "्": return "\\"; case "ऊ": return "pm"; case "-": return " "; case "(": return "-"; case ")": return "_"; } 
}


function stringToArray() {
  var i = 0,
    arr = [],
    codePoint;
  while (!isNaN(codePoint = knownCharCodeAt(str, i))) {
    arr.push(String.fromCodePoint(codePoint));
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

if (!String.fromCodePoint) {
// ES6 Unicode Shims 0.1 , © 2012 Steven Levithan , MIT License
    String.fromCodePoint = function fromCodePoint () {
        var chars = [], point, offset, units, i;
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            point = arguments[i];
            offset = point - 0x10000;
            units = point > 0xFFFF ? [0xD800 + (offset >> 10), 0xDC00 + (offset & 0x3FF)] : [point];
            chars.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, units));
        }
        return chars.join("");
    }
}


function knownCharCodeAt(str, idx) {
  str += '';
  var code,
      end = str.length;

  var surrogatePairs = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g;
  while ((surrogatePairs.exec(str)) != null) {
    var li = surrogatePairs.lastIndex;
    if (li - 2 < idx) {
      idx++;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (idx >= end || idx < 0) {
    return NaN;
  }

  code = str.charCodeAt(idx);

  var hi, low;
  if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) {
    hi = code;
    low = str.charCodeAt(idx + 1);
    // Go one further, since one of the "characters"
    // is part of a surrogate pair
    return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) +
      (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
  }
  return code;
}
```

I strongly recommend just using the first method I made for you though, as it is much easier to control.

Comment: Thank you so much but that only works for single character.What if we give input as कलम that contain 3 character? It will give output as undefined.

Comment: Well then you split that into individual characters first, and perform the process for each one in a loop afterwards. And before you reflexively ask how to do that right away again, please do some research first. The purpose of this site it not to “give you codez”, without you putting in a bit of effort first.

Comment: @Jamin Yes bro,your first method helped me to solve the problem where you used for loop to iterate the string.

Answer (score 0):

You use arrays to search/replace in `str_replace` in PHP

```
$translated_msg = str_replace(["अ","आ","ा","इ","ई","र्","उ","ए","े","ै","ो","ौ","ओ","औ","ं","ँ","ि","ी","ु","ू","क","ख","ग","घ","ङ","च","छ","ज","झ","ञ","ट","ठ","ड","ढ","ण","त","थ","द","ध","न","प","फ","ब","भ","म","य","र","रू","ृ","ल","व","स","श","ष","ज्ञ","ह","१","२","३","४","५","६","७","८","९","०","।","्","ऊ","-","(",")"], ["3","ª","r","5","h","´","`","6","7","8","9","0f","t","y","b","w","g","k","km","a","e","d","o","/","?","[","n","j",";","z","if","1","x","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")",".","\\","pm"," ","-","_"], $some_msg);
```